# Context.SetSessionStateBehavior Usage and Effect upon Session Timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state, session-timeout

When using the [HttpContext.SetSessionStateBehavior Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.setsessionstatebehavior.aspx), if we disable session state like:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    if (!Context.Request.Path.EndsWith("/Service.svc"))
    {
        Context.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Default);
    }
    else
    {
        Context.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled);
    }
}
```

within our Application_BeginRequest method in the Global class, does this mean that any request made where we set SessionStateBehavior.Disabled would not prolong an existing session? In other words, would a request where session state behavior is disabled reset the [HttpSessionState.Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout.aspx) timer?

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this too.  Have you done any testing on it?

Comment: I never did find the answer, though we used a work-around. In our case, what I did was on any request that we didn't want to extend the session, I set session the identifying cookie equal to null within Application_BeginRequest:

private const string AspNetSessionCookieKey = "ASP.NET_SessionId";

if (Context.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains(AspNetSessionCookieKey))
                {
                    Context.Request.Cookies[AspNetSessionCookieKey].Value = null;
                }

Context.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled);